# Download link is not showing for the programmatically added downloadable product to the order

Tags: magento-1.8, orders, downloadable

I have been tasked for creating a order for a downloadable product and placing a order via Paypal and fortunately I've done the task pretty well.

But when the customer get his order email the download link for the product is not showing.

Below in my code that I've used :

```
<?php
if(!isset($_GET['p'])){
    $msg = '<h2>Wrong data passed!!</h2>';
}
else{
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_GET['p']);
$cancel_url = Mage::getURL('').'paypal/standard/cancel/';
$return_url = Mage::getURL('').'paypal/standard/success/';
$notify_url = Mage::getURL('').'paypal/ipn/';

if(Mage::getStoreConfig('payment/paypal_standard/sandbox_flag')=='1'){
    $paypal_url = 'https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?';
}
else{
    $paypal_url = 'https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?';
}
$price = number_format((float)$product->getPrice(),2,'.',''); 
$quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote');

$quote->setCustomerEmail('magegurusit@gmail.com');

$quote->setStore(Mage::app()->getStore());   

$quoteItem = Mage::getModel('sales/quote_item')->setProduct($product);
$quoteItem->setQuote($quote);
$quoteItem->setQty(1);
$quote->addItem($quoteItem);

$addressData = array(
'firstname' => 'Guest',
'lastname' => 'Customer',
'street' => 'Some address on the earth',
'city' => 'Somewhere',
'postcode' => '123456',
'telephone' => '123456',
'country_id' => 'US',
'region_id' => 12, // id from directory_country_region table,
'use_for_shipping'=>1
);

$billingAddress = $quote->getBillingAddress()->addData($addressData);
/*$shippingAddress = $quote->getShippingAddress()->addData($addressData);
$shippingAddress->setCollectShippingRates(true)->collectShippingRates()
->setShippingMethod('flatrate_flatrate')
->setPaymentMethod('paypal_standard');*/

$quote->getPayment()->importData(array('method'=>'paypal_standard'));
$quote->collectTotals()->save();
$service = Mage::getModel('sales/service_quote', $quote);
try {
    $service->submitAll();
    $order = $service->getOrder();
    $invoice = $order->getIncrementId();
} catch (Exception $e){   
    Mage::log($e->getMessage());
}
```

Order is creating properly.
Don't know what little extra I'm missing in the above.
Please help me on this.
Thanks

Comment: Any one has any answer?

Comment: did you ever solve this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> the download link for the product is not showing

This could mean the link as a whole does not show up, the link target is empty or it is not generated at all (no link_hash value) in the database.

The link to the downloadable Product gets generated within the `sales_order_item_save_commit_after` event in the `saveDownloadableOrderItem` method in `Mage_Downloadable_Model_Observer`.

So if it is not generated at all, have a look in your `downloadable_link_purchased_item` database table and check if there are values under `link_hash` and `link_url` or `link_file` fields.

If not, you might have another problem, with your e-mail template maybe.

Answer (score 1):

add this, inspired from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13712475/magento-adding-to-customers-available-downloadable-products

```
$order = $service->getOrder();
$orderItems = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($order->getId());
        foreach ($orderItems->getAllItems() as $itemId => $orderItem) {
            $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($orderItem->getProductId());
            if($product->getTypeId()=='downloadable') {
                $product_links = Mage::getModel('downloadable/product_type')->getLinks( $product );
                foreach ($product_links as $link) {
                    $downloadPurchase = Mage::getModel('downloadable/link_purchased')
                        ->setOrderId($orderItem->getOrderId())
                        ->setOrderIncrementId($orderItems->getIncrementId())
                        ->setOrderItemId($orderItem->getId())
                        ->setCreatedAt(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'))
                        ->setUpdatedAt(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'))
                        ->setCustomerId($orderItems->getCustomerId())
                        ->setProductName($product->getName())
                        ->setProductSku($product->getSku())
                        ->setLinkSectionTitle('Click here to download');

                    $downloadPurchase->save();

                    $linkHash = strtr(base64_encode(microtime() . $downloadPurchase->getId() . $orderItem->getId() . $product->getId()), '+/=', '-_,');
                    $downloadItem = Mage::getModel('downloadable/link_purchased_item')
                        ->setProductId($product->getId())
                        ->setNumberOfDownloadsBought(0)
                        ->setNumberOfDownloadsUsed(0)
                        ->setLinkTitle($link->getTitle())
                        ->setIsShareable($link->getData('is_shareable'))
                        ->setLinkFile($link->getData('link_file'))
                        ->setLinkType('file')
                        ->setStatus('available')
                        ->setCreatedAt(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'))
                        ->setUpdatedAt(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'))
                        ->setLinkHash($linkHash)
                        ->setOrderItemId($orderItem->getId())
                        ->setPurchasedId($downloadPurchase->getId());

                    $downloadItem->save();
                }
            }
        }
```